# thread_local "singleton" - segfault in CURL thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, singleton, libcurl

I have two classes. One is a global singleton (which works as general DBmanager - table checking/creation, etc), the other is a per-thread singleton (which works as data manager - prepared statements and data buffers). Both are implemented in the following way:

**EDIT: See reproducible example at the end**

I also have a function, let's say, `arbitrary_curl_something()` which does a call using easy handle.

I am compiling on Ubuntu server with GCC/G++ 12.1 via a Visual Studio remote development.

It results with a segfault, right when the curl tries to execute, even if the `instance()` is called after. However, when I make the instance in `instance()` just `static` instead of `thread_local` it works fine.

The segfault is shown to happen in `res_mkquery.c`, with following call stack:

```
libc.so.6!__GI___res_context_mkquery(struct resolv_context * ctx, int op, const char * dname, int class, int type, const unsigned char * data, unsigned char * buf, int buflen) Line 117
    at resolv\resolv\res_mkquery.c(117)
libc.so.6!__GI___res_context_query(struct resolv_context * ctx, const char * name, int class, int type, unsigned char * answer, int anslen, unsigned char ** answerp, unsigned char ** answerp2, int * nanswerp2, int * resplen2, int * answerp2_malloced) Line 139
    at resolv\resolv\res_query.c(139)
libc.so.6!__res_context_querydomain(int * answerp2_malloced, int * resplen2, int * nanswerp2, unsigned char ** answerp2, unsigned char ** answerp, int anslen, unsigned char * answer, int type, int class, const char * domain, const char * name, struct resolv_context * ctx) Line 625
    at resolv\resolv\res_query.c(625)
libc.so.6!__GI___res_context_search(struct resolv_context * ctx, const char * name, int class, int type, unsigned char * answer, int anslen, unsigned char ** answerp, unsigned char ** answerp2, int * nanswerp2, int * resplen2, int * answerp2_malloced) Line 381
    at resolv\resolv\res_query.c(381)
libc.so.6!__GI__nss_dns_gethostbyname4_r(const char * name, struct gaih_addrtuple ** pat, char * buffer, size_t buflen, int * errnop, int * herrnop, int32_t * ttlp) Line 373
    at resolv\nss_dns\dns-host.c(373)
libc.so.6!gaih_inet(const char * name, const struct gaih_service * service, const struct addrinfo * req, struct addrinfo ** pai, unsigned int * naddrs, struct scratch_buffer * tmpbuf) Line 747
    at \sysdeps\posix\getaddrinfo.c(747)
libc.so.6!__GI_getaddrinfo(const char * name, const char * service, const struct addrinfo * hints, struct addrinfo ** pai) Line 2240
    at \sysdeps\posix\getaddrinfo.c(2240)
libcurl.so.4![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]
libc.so.6!start_thread(void * arg) Line 442
    at nptl\nptl\pthread_create.c(442)
libc.so.6!clone3() Line 81
    at \sysdeps\unix\sysv\linux\x86_64\clone3.S(81)
```

Or

```
libc.so.6!___ns_name_pack(const unsigned char * src, unsigned char * dst, int dstsiz, const unsigned char ** dnptrs, const unsigned char ** lastdnptr) Line 106
    at resolv\resolv\ns_name_pack.c(106)
libc.so.6!___ns_name_compress(const char * src, unsigned char * dst, size_t dstsiz, const unsigned char ** dnptrs, const unsigned char ** lastdnptr) Line 41
    at resolv\resolv\ns_name_compress.c(41)
libc.so.6!__GI___res_context_mkquery(struct resolv_context * ctx, int op, const char * dname, int class, int type, const unsigned char * data, unsigned char * buf, int buflen) Line 153
    at resolv\resolv\res_mkquery.c(153)
libc.so.6!__GI___res_context_query(struct resolv_context * ctx, const char * name, int class, int type, unsigned char * answer, int anslen, unsigned char ** answerp, unsigned char ** answerp2, int * nanswerp2, int * resplen2, int * answerp2_malloced) Line 139
    at resolv\resolv\res_query.c(139)
libc.so.6!__res_context_querydomain(int * answerp2_malloced, int * resplen2, int * nanswerp2, unsigned char ** answerp2, unsigned char ** answerp, int anslen, unsigned char * answer, int type, int class, const char * domain, const char * name, struct resolv_context * ctx) Line 625
    at resolv\resolv\res_query.c(625)
libc.so.6!__GI___res_context_search(struct resolv_context * ctx, const char * name, int class, int type, unsigned char * answer, int anslen, unsigned char ** answerp, unsigned char ** answerp2, int * nanswerp2, int * resplen2, int * answerp2_malloced) Line 381
    at resolv\resolv\res_query.c(381)
libc.so.6!__GI__nss_dns_gethostbyname4_r(const char * name, struct gaih_addrtuple ** pat, char * buffer, size_t buflen, int * errnop, int * herrnop, int32_t * ttlp) Line 373
    at resolv\nss_dns\dns-host.c(373)
libc.so.6!gaih_inet(const char * name, const struct gaih_service * service, const struct addrinfo * req, struct addrinfo ** pai, unsigned int * naddrs, struct scratch_buffer * tmpbuf) Line 747
    at \sysdeps\posix\getaddrinfo.c(747)
libc.so.6!__GI_getaddrinfo(const char * name, const char * service, const struct addrinfo * hints, struct addrinfo ** pai) Line 2240
    at \sysdeps\posix\getaddrinfo.c(2240)
libcurl.so.4![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code]
libc.so.6!start_thread(void * arg) Line 442
    at nptl\nptl\pthread_create.c(442)
libc.so.6!clone3() Line 81
    at \sysdeps\unix\sysv\linux\x86_64\clone3.S(81)
```

I don't know if this problem is libcurl based, other-library based, thread based or what, and I'm slowly losing my mind over it. I've seen people doing thread-local singletons even on this site, and it worked for them, so I have no idea.

Example to reproduce:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

//#define CURL_STATICLIB // doesnt matter
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <curl/easy.h>

using std::size_t;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

constexpr size_t cnt_sml = 6;
constexpr size_t cnt_big = 1 << 16;

class ThrdLcl
{
    using qr_ptr = std::unique_ptr<int32_t>; // some sql query class
    using dt_ptr = std::unique_ptr<int64_t>; // some data storage struct

private:
    std::array<std::array<            qr_ptr,  cnt_big>, cnt_sml> queries;
    std::array<std::array<std::vector<dt_ptr>, cnt_big>, cnt_sml> buffer;

    ThrdLcl()
    {
        cout << "ThrdLcl constructed!" << endl;
    }
    ~ThrdLcl()
    {
        cout << "ThrdLcl destructed!" << endl;
    }
    ThrdLcl(const ThrdLcl&) = delete;
    ThrdLcl(const ThrdLcl&&) = delete;
    ThrdLcl& operator=(const ThrdLcl&) = delete;
    ThrdLcl& operator=(const ThrdLcl&&) = delete;

public:
    static ThrdLcl* i()
    {
        thread_local ThrdLcl instance;
        return &instance;
    }
};

void do_curl_bullshit()
{
    cout << "Checking CURL..." << endl;
    CURL* ch = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.ipify.org"); // any url
    curl_easy_perform(ch);
    curl_easy_cleanup(ch);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ThrdLcl::i(); // doesnt matter if here
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_NOTHING);
    do_curl_bullshit();
    ThrdLcl::i(); // ...or here
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Of course requires linking libcurl. Compiled with g++ 12.1, C standard 11 and C++ standard 20.
When the instance is made static, everything works fine (only after increasing data size thousandfold, there is a linker error).
When the instance is thread_local, with just half the specified buffer size it works fine. When I create an `std::thread` myself (instead of calling CURL thing) it works fine. When the instance is created on heap and stored in `unique_ptr` again with CURL everything works fine.

However this raises questions:
Why does CURL create threads for a non-parallel interface?
Why *segfault* specifically?
Why did the trace change from the 1st to the 2nd just by changing the number of variables inside the class (not their total size)?
Why does it even matter when nothing is calling `instance()` inside the CURL thread???

Comment: `pthread_create` in the stack dump is missing in the shown code. Be kind to post a [mcve].

Comment: @273K While searching for the possible cause I disabled literally every part of the program, commented out unused headers, removed unused sources from being compiled, until I was left with these two things. There is nothing else in the main(). I am *not* creating any threads. Either CURL creates its own thread or I dont know. That's why it's so confusing, and why I asked on SO.

Comment: @273K Added the smallest example which still reproduces this error. Now go on, tell me that I crEAte A thReaD SOmeWHEre I dare you

Comment: A) that's perhaps not a great attitude to bring to someone making a reasonable request before offering some help.
B) Is it a minimal reproducible example? Did you try creating a thread without using curl at all and seeing what happens? It seems from the stack trace that a thread IS being created for your request.
C) What happens if you make your thread_local a unique_ptr?

Comment: @patros Thanks, added. std::thread works fine, and unique_ptr also works fine.
As for your first point, 1) there aren't many things I hate more than being implied I'm lying; 2) unfortunately SO is widely known for not being too friendly, idk why I'm still trying at this point